# Codeigniter command line not working with database class / driver?

Tags: php, codeigniter, command-line

Has anyone else out there had this problem and found a possible solution. Im not getting any error msg's, simply that no data is been returned from the command line when the database class is either loaded automatically or from the controller.

(This is for CodeIgniter Reactor version.)

**Update:**
Reported this as a bug:
https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter-reactor/issue/85/

Comment: I'm also having the same problem, I need to launch a CI script from my command line and I'm not able to retrieve data from my database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im using cURL to run the script for now and not direct php,

so this:

curl http://localhost/~derrick/mywebsite/index.php/task/run

instead of this:

php Users/derrick/sites/mywebsite/index.php task run

for now until the problem has been resolved.